# How to reduce query time using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql

I am fetching records from MySQL database using Java (JDBC). I have tables -
Stop_Times with 1.5 Million records and
Stops with 1 lac records.

I am using following code

```
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select distinct(stop_id) from Stop_Times force index (idx_stop_times) where agency_id = '" + agency_id + "' and route_type = " + route_type + " order by stop_id");

while(rs.next())
{
  stop_id.add(rs.getString("stop_id"));               
}

JSONArray jsonResult = new JSONArray();

String sql = "select * from Stops force index (idx_Stops) where stop_id = ? and agency_id = ? and location_type = 0 order by stop_name";

                  PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                  int rid = 0;

                  for(int r = 0; r < stop_id.size(); r++)
                  {
                      pstm.setString(1, stop_id.get(r).toString());
                      pstm.setString(2, agency_id);
                      rs = pstm.executeQuery();

                      if(rs.next())
                      {
                          JSONObject jsonStop = new JSONObject();
                          jsonStop.put("str_station_id", rs.getString("stop_id"));
                          jsonStop.put("str_station_name", rs.getString("stop_name") + "_" + rs.getString("stop_id"));
                          jsonStop.put("str_station_code", rs.getString("stop_code"));
                          jsonStop.put("str_station_desc", rs.getString("stop_desc"));
                          jsonStop.put("str_station_lat", rs.getDouble("stop_lat"));
                          jsonStop.put("str_station_lon", rs.getDouble("stop_lon"));
                          jsonStop.put("str_station_url", rs.getString("stop_url"));
                          jsonStop.put("str_location_type", rs.getString("location_type"));
                          jsonStop.put("str_zone_id", rs.getString("zone_id"));

                          jsonResult.put((rid++), jsonStop);
                      }                               
                  }
```

The first query returns 6871 records. But it is taking too much time - on server side it is taking 8-10 seconds and at client side 40-45 seconds.

I want to reduce these times as for server side 300-500 milliseconds and at client side around 10 sec.
Please can anybody help me for how to to this?

Comment: If only the first query is slow, why have you posted the whole java code? Or is the whole function (both queries) slow?

Comment: Most Probably the first query is slower one, but dont know if both queries are taking these times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy is to use a first query to get IDs, and then loop over these IDs and execute another query for each of the IDs found by the first query. You're in fact doing a "manual" join instead of letting the database do it for you. You could rewrite everything in a single query:

```
select * from Stops stops
inner join Stop_Times stopTimes on stopTimes.stop_id = stops.stop_id
where stops.stop_id = ? 
  and stops.agency_id = ? 
  and stops.location_type = 0 
  and stopTimes.agency_id = ? 
  and stopTimes.route_type = ?
order by stops.stop_name
```

Comment: Hi JB, yes my strategy is that. I also tried with Join query with left join then it was taking 70 sec at server side. So I hv separated the queries as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the explain plan associated with your request (Cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) ; avoid full table scan (Explain join ALL). Then add relevant indexes. Then retry.